# KO: Click event not firing in some situations

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm developing a SPA (Single Page Application) that looks like a book.

On the side of the book there are tabs that the user can click in order to navigate to different areas of the book.

The tabs also have transition effect applied to them using CSS3 transitions.

Problem is that sometimes, when I click one of the tabs, I see the transition happen (i.e the tab changes colour and moves 20px to left ) but the click event is not firing and I need to click 3-4 times for it to fire, while in most cases everything works fine.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like the problem is with the rotation (The tabs are rotated in 90deg), if i don't rotate them everything works fine,any idea how to overcome this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="caspBookTabs">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: tabs">
                <li data-bind="text: chapterName, click: $root.selectTab, attr: { 'data-tabName': chapterName }, activeTab: $root.currentTab"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
self.selectTab = function(chapter, e){
        goToPage({ chapter: chapter.chapterName });
        e.preventDefault();
        // e.stopPropagation();
    };
```

**CSS (using LESS):**

```
.caspBookTabs {
    position: absolute;
    top:85px;
    right:-15px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-width : 768px)
    and (max-width : 1024px)
    and (orientation : landscape) {
        top: 75px;
        right:-35px;
    }
    li {
        margin-bottom: 110px;
        height: 33px;
        width: 130px;
        /* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
        @media only screen
        and (min-width : 768px)
        and (max-width : 1024px)
        and (orientation : landscape) {
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        .rotation(90deg);
        display: block;
        background: url('@{caspImgPath}/tabs-i2.png') no-repeat 0 5px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 46px;
        /*padding-top: 20px;*/
        color: @tabsColor;
        .font-size(1.4);
        font-weight: bold;
        .transition-property(right);
        position: relative;
        right:0;
        &:hover {
            background-position: 0 -40px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        &:active {
            right: 10px;
        }
    }
    .caspActiveTab {
        right: 10px;
        background-position: 0 -40px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the goToPage function defined? In scope of your view model? Or in global scope? Do you get any error in javascript console?

Comment: @Grim - It is defined in my VM, but like i said the click event itself is not firing (i.e. the function `selectTab` is not even called) so it doesn't really matter where is `goToPage` defined.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, not sure it is the best one but that is the only one i've got, feel free to post other ideas if you have any:

After some testing it seems like the problem occurs when using `rotation` and `transition` on the same element, if I use only one of them everything seems to work.

So I just removed the CSS transition and instead mimic the effect using `jQuery.animate()`.